# Detail learning of c++ design patterns

Tags: c++, design-patterns, oop

Thanks for your valuable time.

I want to learn c++ design patterns. I searched on web but I was not getting  documents which gives me better details about design patterns. I was getting good details but those were in different URL's, I required all the information in one place only so that it will be better to know what all things are there under c++ design patterns.

Below are my necessary things while learning design patterns :

- Why we need c++ design patterns
- What is design patterns
- How they are categorized ( I mean overview we can say)
- Good approach while implementation of these patterns
- Pros and cons of design patterns
- New features in design patterns.

Please folks suggest me good stuff which consist of above mentioned points. Also suggest me , is there any good forum available for design patterns.

Thanks for your suggestions !!!

-Pravin

Comment: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming

Comment: Why do you want to learn C++ design patterns?

Comment: @FredOverflow: Yes...after going through tech docs I got to know that , design patterns are common concept...i thought some topics are different in c++ ( implementation wise )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Vince Huston has a sketchy website... but it neatly illustrate implementations of all the Design Patterns mentionned in the GOF book in C++.

[Check it out](http://www.vincehuston.org/dp/) :)

Each pattern is presented with several sections:

- name (thanks Lou for pointing it out :P)
- intent
- problem (that it solves)
- structure summary (with a nice diagram)
- discussion
- structure (with a sketchy diagram)
- example
- check-list (so that you know WHEN to apply it)
- before / after (to see it in action)
- rules of thumb (comparison with the other patterns, why they differ, how they can be combined)

It's pretty complete and a really handy reference, though once you've groked a pattern, you should be able to come up with an implementation all by yourself, and even throw templates in the mix :)

Comment: Don't forget "a name"  -- it's the most important part.  The name helps spread the idea and make it easy to talk about.

Comment: @Lou Franco: right, without a proper name the rest is just a pile of information :)

Comment: @Lou Franco and @Matthieu M. - and you can't put a pile of information on your resume, yet you can put the 'proper name'- it's so much useful :)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with JD that many valuable design patterns aren't language specific.

However, the implementation of patterns is often language specific. I found Alexandrescu's book "Modern C++ Design" very interesting to see how he uses C++ templates to implement generic version of patterns like Singleton, Visitor etc.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous question, I came across [sourcemaking](http://sourcemaking.com/), where at least, there is a nice overview of the basic design patterns (and anti-patterns).  I don't know of 1 complete design patterns overview, so I guess, I'll check here for a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

Design patterns are not generally specific to one language, so I would suggest you google specific design patterns such as the mediator pattern, facade pattern, etc... There are 23 base patterns.

Really it depends upon your intentions for a program as to what pattern you decide upon. There are many good books out there which discuss each pattern in detail with real life.

Have a read on google books of the original book "design patterns: elements of reusable object oriented software" for am in depth discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Head first design patterns...
[http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)